# Change animation after popup is shown

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Is it possible to change the animation on a Rg.Plugins.Popup after it has been shown. I have tried binding the Animation property to a viewmodel and change the animation before popup is commanded to disappear, but popup still use old animation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

FYI

Use this method to change animation after popup is shown.

```
protected override void OnDisappearingAnimationBegin()
```